# Unable to correctly install Adobe InDesign CC in OSX 10.9

Tags: macos, installation, osx-mavericks, adobe-indesign, adobe-creative-cloud

Myself and the senior Mac technician at my office have been working on a users machine for the past 3 days and we can't seem to get anywhere. hopefully you can help us.

- There was an earlier semi-related issue where we couldn't get the Adobe CC manager program installed due to an issue where it already thought it was installed but this has since been resolved.

The primary problem is that after installing InDesign CC 2015.5 on the users machine, they will be unable to launch it due to the error message below.

> [image]

Before deleting anything (wouldn't want the user losing their data), we went into all folders in ~/library and user/library that reference adobe and preferences, added the user to that folder's permissions group and made sure the changes were applied to all child folders.
Despite doing this, we would still see the error message.

We've gone through many troubleshooting steps involving uninstalling using the CC desktop tool, running the Adobe Cleaner, rebooting and reinstalling.

- I should note that we've attempted all these steps in both the users account and our administrator account. We were at one point able to get InDesign to launch correctly but only in the admin account. We could immediately log out of admin, log back into the user account and ID would have the same error message as when we started.

All these steps did not make any changes to the issue. Occasionally, on reinstalling the progress will get stuck at 99% for 20-30+ minutes without any movement. Upon logging out and back in for reinstallation, the CC manager program will say that InDesign has an update. When I go to install that update, the progress will proceed to the end and an error will appear saying "update failed".

Here is the install log:
http://pastebin.com/aJTJAuSy

EDIT: After attempting an install and waiting 20min at 99%, InDesign did fully install. Though, we still are getting the above error message.

At this point, I'm ready to do a full uninstall of all Adobe CC Software and reinstall from scratch. I just want to make sure I do it right.

Is there a guide online for how to fully remove all Adobe CC software from a users machine before a clean install? And has anyone has any experience with the issues I mentioned?

Much appreciated

Comment: "added the user to that folder's permissions group"... User should be owner of that folder, group would normally be staff `rwxr-xr-x user staff`[though I've not tested on a non-admin account]

Answer (score 0):

We were finally able to resolve the issue. After deleting the Preferences folder from /Preferences and /Caches, InDesign opened normally

Application "Roaming Data Folder"

```
/Users/[User Name]/Library/Preferences/Adobe InDesign/
```

Application "local cached data folder"

```
/Users/[User Name]/Library/Caches/Adobe InDesign/
```

https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/kb/indesign-preferences-support-file-locations.html